# How to redirect to a given page depending on the user locale?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, localization

Is there a way to redirect an user depending on is browser locale ?

For instance, I'd like to redirect to a page called index.en.html all users who doesn't have their browser locale set to French.

Could I do this with Apache and .htaccess ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well looking at the documentation I found the MultiViews option.

```
Options MultiViews
AddLanguage fr .fr
AddLanguage en .en
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
     LanguagePriority fr en
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able [to match](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) the environment variable `%{HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE}` or the HTTP header `Accept-Language` (with `%{HTTP:Accept-Language}`) for `fr` or `fr-fr`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mod_rewrite` and test for the `Accept-Language` header. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} en-us
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en-us/$1 [L]
```

Better yet, take a look at `mod_negotiation`

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html